# JsonAttribute only for deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

Searching for my ussue throught google, but don't found same issues.
In my asp.net core 3 web api i realize controller receiving data from OpenWeatherApi, and want to pass it to my mobile app. I receive this data structure from this OpenWeatherApi (only one class for example)

```
"coord": {
    "lon": 37.61,
    "lat": 55.76
}
```

So in my webapi I use this class to deserialize this:

```
 public class WeatherForecast
 {
    [JsonProperty("coord")]
    public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }
        
  }

public class Coordinates 
    {
        [JsonProperty("lon")]
        public float Longitude { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("lat")]
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```

And when i want to pass data to my mobile app, I have property names, like in OpenWeatherApi (because of using JsonProperty attribute).
How i can pass data to my app use property name when serialize object?

Comment: Why do you want to tightly bind / couple your mobile app's communication contract to an external vendors' communication contract? They should evolve separately. That's why you should introduce and use different models in different contracts.

Answer (score 1):

You can define [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples):

```
class IgnoreJsonPropertyAttributeNameResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName; // use property name
        }
        return props;
    }
}
```

And use it for serialization:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new IgnoreJsonPropertyAttributeNameResolver()
};
var wf = new WeatherForecast
{
    Coordinates = new Coordinates {Latitude = 1, Longitude = 2} 
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wf, settings)); // prints "{"Coordinates":{"Longitude":2.0,"Latitude":1.0}}"
```